# Two questions on Zuber's "KdV and W-flows"

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, integrable-systems, virasoro-algebra

I'm having difficulty following computations in the paper "[KdV and W-flows](http://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~zuber/MesPapiers/CdJ91.pdf)" by Zuber.

On pg. 2, what would be the conserved quantity $I_4$, related to the conservation laws of the KdV hierarchy? (Off-chance connection to face polynomials of associahedra.)

On pg. 3, how to interpret the Poisson bracket in Eqn. 2.8 to explicitly derive the RHS? ($u_n$ as defined by Eqn. 2.7 is a scalar, so the bracket makes no sense to me. This is supposedly an analogue to the celebrated Virasoro central extension of the Witt Lie algebra.)

Answer (score 3):

As for $I_4$ and $I_j$ for all $j\geqslant 4$ up to overall sign factors, see e.g. equation (1.9) of [these lecture notes](http://www.tp2.rub.de/~maximp/learning/seminar5.pdf) with $u=-r$. Also you may wish to look at [this link](https://wikiwaves.org/Conservation_Laws_for_the_KdV).

Regarding the bracket at p.3, the point is that in fact the brackets considered by the author are defined on *functionals*, which $u_n$ indeed are, and this is the proper way to interpret formulas like the one immediately after (2.4); for Poisson brackets on functionals, including in particular the KdV case, see e.g. Chapter 7 of [Applications of Lie groups to differential equations](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781468402742) by Peter Olver.